# Display text in grid upon mouse click - pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am learning pygame and I am trying to create minesweeper. I have the grid all set up and got it so when you click on a grid if there is a mine there it changes the grid square red,if there are no mines around the square it turns the square black(the color of the board), and when there is a mine around the square it doesn't change color but i cannot get it so that when there is a mine around the square it shows how many in that square. my code is below:

```
import pygame
import random

BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
GREY = (200,200,200)

pygame.init()

box = 11

size = (265,265)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 12)
text1 = font.render('1',True, RED)
text2 = font.render('2',True, WHITE)
text3 = font.render('3',True, WHITE)
text4 = font.render('4',True, WHITE)
text5 = font.render('5',True, WHITE)
text6 = font.render('6',True, WHITE)
text7 = font.render('7',True, WHITE)
text8 = font.render('8',True, WHITE)
rect1 = text1.get_rect()
rect2 = text2.get_rect()
rect3 = text3.get_rect()
rect4 = text4.get_rect()
rect5 = text5.get_rect()
rect6 = text6.get_rect()
rect7 = text7.get_rect()
rect8 = text8.get_rect()
width = 23
height = 23
margin = 1


pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")


done = False


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

grid = []
for row in range(box):
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(box):
        grid[row].append(0)

def updatevalue(rn, c, grid):
    # change row above
    if rn-1 > -1:
        r = grid[rn-1]

        if c-1 > -1:
            if not r[c-1] == '*' and not r[c-1] == '!':
                r[c-1]+= 1

        if not r[c] == '*' and not r[c] == '!':
            r[c]+= 1

        if c+1 < 10:
            if not r[c+1] == '*' and not r[c+1] == '!':
                r[c+1]+= 1

    #change same row                
    r = grid[rn]

    if c-1 > -1:
        if not r[c-1] == '*' and not r[c-1] == '!':
            r[c-1]+= 1

    if not r[c] == '*' and not r[c] == '!':
        r[c]+= 1

    if c+1 < 10:
        if not r[c+1] == '*' and not r[c+1] == '!':
            r[c+1]+= 1

    #change row below
    if rn+1 < 10:
        r = grid[rn +1]

        if c-1 > -1:
            if not r[c-1] == '*' and not r[c-1] == '!':
                r[c-1]+= 1

        if not r[c] == '*' and not r[c] == '!':
            r[c]+= 1

        if c+1 < 10:
            if not r[c+1] == '*' and not r[c+1] == '!':
                r[c+1]+= 1     

for i in range(10):
    r = random.randint(0,10)
    c = random.randint(0,10)
    grid[r][c] = '!'
    updatevalue(r, c, grid)



while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos =pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            column = pos[0]//(width+margin)
            row = pos[1]//(height+margin)
            if grid[row][column] == '!':
                grid[row][column] = '*'
            if grid[row][column] == 0:
                grid[row][column] = '_'
            if grid[row][column] == 1:
                grid[row][column] = '1'
                rect1.topleft = (row,column)
            if grid[row][column] == 2:
                grid[row][column] = '2'
            if grid[row][column] == 3:
                grid[row][column] = '3'
            if grid[row][column] == 4:
                grid[row][column] = '4'
            if grid[row][column] == 5:
                grid[row][column] = '5'
            if grid[row][column] == 6:
                grid[row][column] = '6'
            if grid[row][column] == 7:
                grid[row][column] = '7'
            if grid[row][column] == 8:
                grid[row][column] = '8'
            #print('Click ', pos, 'Grid coordinates: (', row,',', column,')')
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            done = True



    for r in range(box):
        for c in range(box):
            num = grid[r][c]
            color = WHITE
            if grid[r][c] == '_':
                color = BLACK
            if grid[r][c] == '*':
                color = RED


            pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,
                             [margin+c*(margin+width),
                              margin +r*(margin+height),width,height])
            if grid[r][c] == '1':
                screen.blit(text1,rect1)


    pygame.display.flip()


    clock.tick(60)







pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code uses a integer to represent an un-clicked "near-mine" cell.  Then it's converted to a string representation of the same number when clicked.

It's easy to implement the number-drawing by putting all the number-images into a python dictionary, keyed on this string.  So `digit_images["8"]` gives you the rendered text for the 8.  The other text-numbers were rendered to WHITE, I'm not sure this would show properly on a white background.  This was changed to RED.

When a cell is clicked the number `8` is changed to a string `"8"`.  In the main loop we check the `type()` of `grid[r][c]`.  If it's a number still, well that means it's un-clicked.  If it's changed into string (meaning it *is* clicked), use that string to find the correct number-image.  This form of checking also allows the code to have a lot less lines, since we're not checking for 8 different forms of the result.

It might be a better approach to store a list for each cell with a state, rather than using a single string/not-string to determine clicked-ness.  Maybe something like:

```
grid[row][column] = [ '*', False ]   # content, is-clicked
```

Or maybe even a class:

```
class Cell:
    def __init__( self, value ):
        self.value = value
        self.clicked = False

    def isClicked( self ):
        return self.clicked

    def getValue( self ):
        return self.value
```

Here is the working code:

```
import pygame
import random

BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED   = (255,0,0)
GREY  = (200,200,200)

pygame.init()

box = 11

size = (265,265)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 12)
text1 = font.render('1',True, RED)
text2 = font.render('2',True, RED)
text3 = font.render('3',True, RED)
text4 = font.render('4',True, RED)
text5 = font.render('5',True, RED)
text6 = font.render('6',True, RED)
text7 = font.render('7',True, RED)
text8 = font.render('8',True, RED)
# Dictionary to map the string value to the image
digit_images = { '1':text1, '2':text2, '3':text3, '4':text4,
                 '5':text5, '6':text6, '7':text7, '8':text8  }

width = 23
height = 23
margin = 1


pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

grid = []
for row in range(box):
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(box):
        grid[row].append(0)

def updatevalue(rn, c, grid):
    # change row above
    if rn-1 > -1:
        r = grid[rn-1]

        if c-1 > -1:
            if not r[c-1] == '*' and not r[c-1] == '!':
                r[c-1]+= 1

        if not r[c] == '*' and not r[c] == '!':
            r[c]+= 1

        if c+1 < 10:
            if not r[c+1] == '*' and not r[c+1] == '!':
                r[c+1]+= 1

    #change same row                
    r = grid[rn]

    if c-1 > -1:
        if not r[c-1] == '*' and not r[c-1] == '!':
            r[c-1]+= 1

    if not r[c] == '*' and not r[c] == '!':
        r[c]+= 1

    if c+1 < 10:
        if not r[c+1] == '*' and not r[c+1] == '!':
            r[c+1]+= 1

    #change row below
    if rn+1 < 10:
        r = grid[rn +1]

        if c-1 > -1:
            if not r[c-1] == '*' and not r[c-1] == '!':
                r[c-1]+= 1

        if not r[c] == '*' and not r[c] == '!':
            r[c]+= 1

        if c+1 < 10:
            if not r[c+1] == '*' and not r[c+1] == '!':
                r[c+1]+= 1     

for i in range(10):
    r = random.randint(0,10)
    c = random.randint(0,10)
    grid[r][c] = '!'
    updatevalue(r, c, grid)



while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos =pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            column = pos[0]//(width+margin)
            row = pos[1]//(height+margin)
            if grid[row][column] == '!':
                grid[row][column] = '*'
            if grid[row][column] == 0:
                grid[row][column] = '_'
            # If the click was an a previously-unclicked area, show the number
            # indicated by converting the number to a string
            if type( grid[row][column] is int ):
                grid[row][column] = str( grid[row][column] )
            #print('Click ', pos, 'Grid coordinates: (', row,',', column,')')

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            done = True



    for r in range(box):
        for c in range(box):
            num = grid[r][c]
            color = WHITE
            if grid[r][c] == '_':
                color = BLACK
            if grid[r][c] == '*':
                color = RED

            pygame.draw.rect(screen,color, [margin+c*(margin+width), margin +r*(margin+height),width,height])

            ### If the cell is a string-digit, is has been clicked
            ### Draw the correct digit-string-image in the cell.
            if ( type( grid[r][c] ) is str and grid[r][c] in '12345678' ):
                screen.blit( digit_images[ grid[r][c] ], [margin+c*(margin+width), margin +r*(margin+height),width,height] )

#            if grid[r][c] == '1':
#                screen.blit(text1,rect1)


    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```